# If else for css

Tags: php, html, css

Can i use if else statement for css?

This is where i want the color of the text to change:

```
<?php echo $status; ?>
```

There will be 2 status: Pending & Delivered
Pending will be red color and delivered will be green

Can i do something like (for CSS):

```
.pending {text-decoration:underline; color:red;}
.delivered {text-decoration:underline; color:green;}
```

and if else statement:

```
if ($status==delivered)
{
   //this is where i don't know what to do and code
}
else
{
   //and here
}
```

What should i put there? Or any other solution?

Comment: If you find any of the answers helpful, please accept it, clicking the tick icon under the score.

Answer (score 1):

Output html with php / javascript / any other language, and assign classes to the whatever element you want.

pure PHP example:

```
<?php

if(true) {

echo '<div class="pending">content</div>';

} else {

echo '<div class="delivered">content</div>';

}

?>
```

Another way using variables (PHP + html):

```
<?php

if(true) {

$status = 'pending';

} else {

$status = 'delivered';

}

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="<?php echo $status; ?>">content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `$status` variable in PHP actually matches your class names, just use it in your PHP when displaying whatever the thing is that's being styled:

e.g. if `$status == 'pending'`, then:

```php
<div class="<?= $status ?>">...</div>
```

will render

```html
<div class="pending">...</div>
```

and match your `.pending` rule.